# Rails LIKE query using mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to do a Like query matching substrings. I previously used this:

```
products = Product.where("title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:s_term]}%", "%#{params[:s_term]}%")
```

which worked great with sqlite3 (not worried about sql injection right now).
However, I just switched to mysql, and when I perform the query it whines about Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xC2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):
because of the '%' in the query. Is there a way for me to escape this or do this differently in my where query?

Comment: When you execute this command in the rails console, can you comment here the equivalent sql command it generates? thanks

Comment: I get this in the console: ` Product Load (142.3ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE (title LIKE '%as%' OR description LIKE '%as%')
`, which works great for what I want to do! It just seams to be a problem from the actual code.

Comment: if I run the exact same code from my code base, rails produces `Product Load (3.7ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE (title LIKE '%as%' OR description LIKE '%as%')`, but comes back with the above mentioned error!

Comment: I think SO is messing up the backticks, but I copied both commands into gedit and they are exactly the same, so I think this must have something to do with just the encoding. I've added a utf8 meta-tag in my html hoping that might fix the problem, but it did nothing.

Comment: if it helps, I just looked up the character code it is complaining about, and it is the typical "A" with circumflex that you see when a character is not recognized.

Comment: ok, I've found the crux of the problem: I'm importing my products from a csv that apparently contains non-utf8 characters. It seams that mysql has allowed those characters to be stored in the database, but rails then complains when those characters are retrieved. I'm trying to get rid of these characters, but had no luck so far. I've tried using the encode! function to disallow these characters from entering into my database in the first place (in my import function). Any ideas what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

After an odesy of encoding "adventures", the problem turned out to be that the file I was "importing" to my database contained strings that were not utf8 and ascii compatible (the problem was specifically this character: Â). In the function I was using to add the strings to my database, I used this to keep these characters from entering into my db:

```
thestring.gsub(/\P{ASCII}/, '').encode('utf-8')
```

Now I can be sure that everything in my database is encoded correctly and searches will not return results that rails cannot handle for encoding reasons!

an alternative may be :

```
thestring.delete!("^\u{0000}-\u{007F}").encode('utf-8')
```

This alternative did not work for me, but may work with some ruby/rails versions.

Comment: Im glad you got it all worked out :) I am sorry I have not been of any more help to you.